# Is a stack a data structure or not?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

In my textbook, after covering the abstract data type, stack, where we implement it, the book states:

> Now we consider the use of a fundamental data structure that is an
>   appropriate choice for representing the data in a collection ADT
>   implementation.  This is our ﬁrst example of building a data structure that is not directly supported by the Java language. The Linked list...

My confusion lies in the fact that whenever I look at online tutorials, they refer to a stack as being a basic data structure. Yet, in this book, after covering implementing a stack (writing the code), it states that the Linked List is the first data structure being covered in the book. I'm confused.

Comment: Can you give us a few more sentences from that passage? With the minimal context you've given, it's impossible to figure out what the author is trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your quotation, linked lists aren't the first data structure being covered by the book but they are the first data structure "*not directly supported by the Java Language*" which is covered by the book.

Java has had [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) in its standard library since version 1.2 so unless your book is very old, I think your author means that Java linked lists are **indirectly supported**, because they are written in Java, as opposed to being **directly supported** if they had been a fundamental type in the Java language itself.

Comment: My textbook came out in 2013. The textbook started off discussing stack and queues and then discussed Linked List. Though, prior to discussing linked lists, they used array based implementations for stack and queue.